# How can I split an army in Rome 2 Total War?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

I got Rome 2 today and am playing the prologue. So far I am quite satisfied by the game, but something seems to be bothering me or simply doesn't work. In older Total War games you could simply build units which you could manoeuvre around without a general (a "general" would be appointed to one of the units). Now you need to first build a general and then build an army. I can understand that, men need men to follow. But something doesn't seem to work properly.

Let's say I have a general with 3 units of hastati, the general, and 2 units of equites. I need to do a rescue mission to one of my cities so I select 2 units of hastati and one unit of equites and want to move them to the other city. I simply can't. Even though I *only* selected the units needed, the whole army is moved (with its general). The same happens when I try to join part of the army with a fleet.

I cannot create a new general, so that's not it. You simply can't split a unit from its general of whom it originated?

Comment: Isn't it possible to make another general in the army itself? Because when my general died in combat, i had to pick a new general and voila he was there in that same army where the old one died.

Comment: No. It's just a special case (actually,generals recruited so don't cost,and are directly attached to the army) Also,there can't be more generals in an army,so the only way is to get him from somewhere else. If you don't have more legions available,you can disband one if you really need to recruit a general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only way to "split" an army seems to be having two generals. When you order a general to march to another general, you get a possibility to change troops from on army to another.

Compared to other TW games this seems like a huge drawback to be, because you dont seem to be able to recruit troops to undefended city if there is no general present nor can you leave troops to defend a city when your army marches on. City garrisons are usually not enough to defend a city and you need to carefully place your armies.

It does have a certain point, because roman armies were strictly hierarchical and there had to be a general leading it. It leads some inconsistencies tho, like in case your general is killed, you will be able to recruit a new one to that spot immediately.

Comment: I really wish that it let you assign a second in command to each army, who would replace the army if the first died and could split off into a seperate army if needed. Plus let you assign generals as captains of the guard of a city who can sally out only. Would solve pretty much all my complaints with the system.

Answer (score 2):

You can exchange units between 2 generals at least. But as far as I know, all units must be in the company of a general or an admiral (except for agents ofc)

Also, the number of generals you can have at any given time is dependant on your "imperium".
You recruit generals from city centers.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm pretty sure you can't split units off from the general that originated them.

This is probably to try to fit the time period better.  Romans generally moved in force, you would rarely have individual units running around, or troops spread out, instead there were a number of legions stationed throughout the provinces.

And secondly, for much of Roman history (particularly post-Republic), armies were generally more loyal to their general than to Rome itself.  Hence Caesar's crossing of the Rubicon; his troops were loyal enough to him to be willing to march on Rome itself.

(Whether this actually makes the game better is debatable)

Answer (score 0):

You need another general. Recruit him in the closest city and bring him near the army,then you can transfer the units. Unlike previous Total War titles,captains are there just in rare situations,such as killing the enemy general with a spy and attacking the army in the same turn.